# What is the "code" after the app package name in /data/app/?

Tags: applications

Just by curiosity, since I wasn't able to find an answer after googling, do you know what are these "codes" after the packages names of my apps in `/data/app/…`?

This number is neither in `androidmanifest.xml`, nor in `cert.sf`, nor in `manifest.mf` (inside the meta-inf folder).

For example the package name of Clash of Clans is followed by the "code": `com.supercell.clashofclans-Bd6GIb47XTzpL16jgR1kZA==`

[image]

Comment: See also the identical question in [Stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47958947/base64-apk-path).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a random string appended to apps installation path in order to force developers don't hard-code paths in apps, instead use proper APIs.

Quoted from [Android 8.0 Behavior Changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/android-8.0-changes#security-all):

> You can no longer assume that APKs reside in directories whose names end in -1 or -2. Apps should use [`sourceDir`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ApplicationInfo.html#sourceDir) to get the directory, and not rely on the directory format directly.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination. But why don't they want people to hard-code the path, is it a security?

Comment: @sebastienfinor you are right, also they have put this point under **Security** heading.

Comment: @sebastienfinor The [commit message](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/5e10e8f1b2126f031b976b853c3f150418f3b342) that introduces these changes says: "This prevents apps (both normal and ephemeral) from learning what
applications are installed by checking for the existence of
/data/app/com.example.package-1."