# How to find the files (.apk) of a certain app like Google Play Services

Tags: applications, google-play-services, google-apps, search

I have a rooted device and I tried the `find / -name "*Play*"` command and got some files from `com.google.android.gms` and a couple of Playlists but nothing like `Google Play Services.apk`

I wonder if it is possible for an app to not have an .apk file and if this is the case is there any chance of finding the files associated with the app from the app name?

Comment: Check `/data/app/com.google.android.gms- 
 BsVSA3EfHVEHqoT_2Mu_nw==/base.apk`  Play Services are `com.google.android.gms`

Comment: `.apk` files of all system and user apps are accessible even without root. GMS is usually installed to `/system/app` and `/system/priv-app` (or possibly in `/product` partition). Updates go to `/data/app/` like user apps. The string after package name is randomly generated at install time: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215904/218526

Comment: The apk file name usually bases on the package name of an app, not of the localized app name which is defined in the AndroidManifest respectively the app resources.arsc file within the apk.

Comment: `adb shell pm path com.google.android.gms | awk -F':' '{print $2}'` should do the trick. The resulting string can then be used with `adb pull $path` to grab the APK from the device and store it on your computer. No root needed, as was already pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

You won't need root for that, but can utilize the `pm` command either on-device from within a terminal, or via [adb](/questions/tagged/adb):

```
adb shell pm path com.google.android.gms | awk -F':' '{print $2}
```

will give you the full path including the file name, so you could use that to pull the APK from your device to your computer:

```
adb pull $(adb shell pm path com.google.android.gms | awk -F':' '{print $2})
```

To answer the other parts from your question:

- every app has an `*.apk` file. Some might even have multiple ("split APKs").
- finding the APK by the (localized) app name is not trivial. You'd have to parse the entire app list to get the package names, use those to get the location of the APK as described above, and then use `aapt` to extract and match the localized name (I haven't yet found whether and if where Android might store that outside the APK). `aapt` usually isn't present on-device.